# counting values from json to pandas while keeping date-time sorting

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

```
    {"id": 814984317021495298, "date": "2016-12-30", "time": "18:59:37", "timezone": 
    "-0400", "replies_count": 7708, "username": "im_theantitrump"}
    {"id": 814984316195311616, "date": "2016-12-30", "time": "18:59:37", "timezone": 
    "-0400", "replies_count": 25772, "username": "bishyoucray2"}
```

Json file looks like this. When running following commands:

```
    df = pd.read_json('filename.json', lines=True)
    df['date'].value_counts()
```

the result looks like this:

```
    ,date
    2016-11-17,3403
    2016-11-04,2605
    2016-12-09,2285
    2016-11-24,1934
    2016-12-19,1874
    2016-12-07,1864
    2016-11-28,1825
    2016-11-29,1715
    2016-11-27,1688
    2016-12-15,1683
    2016-12-06,1680
```

Is there any alternative that would keep date-time sorted in ascending order (it is ascending on json file by default). And perhaps add 'count' as a second header of the dataframe so it would align with columns?
Here is an example.

```
    date    count
    10/31/2016  97
    11/1/2016   3360
    11/2/2016   5719
    11/3/2016   1206
    11/4/2016   3888
    11/5/2016   1176
    11/6/2016   1598
    11/7/2016   4542
    11/8/2016   1750
    11/9/2016   1224
    11/10/2016  1489
    11/11/2016  3138
    11/12/2016  1449
    11/13/2016  1299
    11/14/2016  1136
    11/15/2016  1525
```

Comment: can't you just pass `, sort=False` to `value_counts()`?

Comment: that messed up month sorting on top of the previous day mixing

Answer (score 1):

To save the output of `.value_counts` in sorted order you can do:

```py
out = df["date"].value_counts().to_frame(name="count")
out = out.sort_index()
out.to_csv("data.csv", index_label="date")
```

Saves `data.csv`:

```
date,count
2016-11-30,2
2016-12-30,2
```

---

Json data used:

```json
{"id": 814984317021495298, "date": "2016-12-30", "time": "18:59:37", "timezone": "-0400", "replies_count": 7708, "username": "im_theantitrump"}
{"id": 814984316195311616, "date": "2016-12-30", "time": "18:59:37", "timezone": "-0400", "replies_count": 25772, "username": "bishyoucray2"}
{"id": 814984316195311616, "date": "2016-11-30", "time": "18:59:37", "timezone": "-0400", "replies_count": 25772, "username": "bishyoucray2"}
{"id": 814984316195311616, "date": "2016-11-30", "time": "18:59:37", "timezone": "-0400", "replies_count": 25772, "username": "bishyoucray2"}
```

Comment: the "date" does not appear in the header now.  " ,count" is the only header now. But, sorting works. Thank you:)